# V/HLOOKUP across spreadsheets returns #VALUE! error

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, worksheet-function

I am trying to pull data from one spreadsheet to another. One of the spreadsheets pulls out the data from MS Access. All my data was updated and when I dragged the rows to update current data it shows #VALUE! in every cell which I tried to update.

```
=VLOOKUP($A1,'From Access'!$A$101:$BBB$113,HLOOKUP(Presentation!AFI$2,'From Access'!$A$101:$BBB$113,13,FALSE),FALSE)/1000000
```

The second last step in formula evaluation comes to:

```
=VLOOKUP("XYZ Industries",'From Access'!$A$101:$BBB$113,0,FALSE)/1000000
```

while the previously updated cells have some value instead of zero like `800`, `805` etc.

```
=VLOOKUP("XYZ Industries",'From Access'!$A$101:$BBB$113,**somevalue**,FALSE)/1000000
```

What can be the issue?

Comment: How to do check that?

Comment: Thanks but that doesnt show me where is the error liek it gives me #value!/1000000 in the final step .Is this problem can be because of spreadsheet I am pulling from

Comment: The Second last step is where error comes I have edited the second last step in question

Comment: You are right it was an index problem . Thanks I did not drag the original index in the other spreadsheet. thanks

Comment: Just as an additional point: I would always advise using `INDEX()` and `MATCH()` when searching for data both horizontally and vertically in an array.

Comment: Please write the answer that solved your problem and mark it as the accepted answer to close this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP’s formula was properly constructed but being fed a parameter for [col_index-num](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx) in a VLOOKUP from a formula that returned `0`:

> If col_index_num is:
>
> •  Less than 1, VLOOKUP returns the #VALUE! error value.